# Add a dictionary into another one with a loop in Django

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to make a *Django Rest API*. With this API, I want to send a list of product. For that, I tried to make a for loop to upgrade my dictionary which contain my data.

This is my code :

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import product, by_product

#List all the products
@api_view(['GET'])
def listing(request):
    context = {}
    product = product.objects.filter(dispo=1).order_by('name')
    for product in product:
        if not product.price_kg:
            price = product.price_uni
            unit = 'units'
        else:
            price = product.price_kg
            unit = 'Kg'

        dictionary = {
            'id' : product.id,
            'name': product.name,
            'price': price,
            'unit': unit,
            'category': product.categorie,
            'byProduct': [],
        }

        context = ({**context, **dictionary}) #Upgrade my dictionary
        
        by_products = by_product.objects.filter(product_id=product.id).order_by('bycat')
        
        for byprod in by_products:
            context['byProduct'].append({
            'id' : byprod.id,
            'name' : byprod.bycat,
            })
        if product.redu:
            context['oldPrice'] = product.redu
            
    return Response(context)
```

In my JSON file, I just get data for the last product.

Comment: You mean like `{'a':3,'b':5,'c'5}` you want to get `{'c':5}`?

Comment: @AnnZen Not exactly, I have for exemple two items : ```{'a' : 3, 'b': 2}``` and ```{'c': 1, 'd': 5}``` and I want to get one dictionary : ```{'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 5}```

Comment: You only want to merge dictionaries, or do you also want to get the last value?

Comment: @AnnZen Yes I want to merge dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per my understanding you want output in this format

e.g { dict 1} , {dict 2} ......... {dict n} while you want to add fields such as `id, name` in `byProduct` key and `oldPrice` also. (that's what I am assuming from your question). Probably you can do something like this :

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def listing(request):
    context = []
    product = product.objects.filter(dispo=1).order_by('name')
    for product in product:
        if not product.price_kg:
            price = product.price_uni
            unit = 'units'
        else:
            price = product.price_kg
            unit = 'Kg'

        dictionary = {
            'id' : product.id,
            'name': product.name,
            'price': price,
            'unit': unit,
            'category': product.categorie,
            'byProduct': [],
        }   
        by_products = by_product.objects.filter(product_id=product.id).order_by('bycat')
        
        for byprod in by_products:
            dictionary['byProduct'].append({
            'id' : byprod.id,
            'name' : byprod.bycat,
            })
        if product.redu:
            dictionary['oldPrice'] = product.redu
        context.append(dictionary) #Upgrade my dictionary
    return Response(context)
```

Comment: I tried to do what you suggested by I get this error : _list indices must be integers or slices, not str_

Comment: Can you do paste the changes you have done on a pastebin link ?? https://pastebin.com/ and paste the link here then.

Comment: What exactly do you want ? The entire file or just the view ?

Comment: Finaly it worked, thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to upgrade your dictionary:

```
context.update(dictionary)
```

According to the comments, this basically wants to merge dictionaries:

```
lst = [{'a':1, 'b':2}, {'c':3, 'd':4}, {'e':5, 'f':6}]

dct = {k:v for d in lst for k,v in d.items()}

print(dct)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 6}
```